# Notify android user when "request_status" changed in MySQL database

Tags: php, android, mysql, android-notifications

Actually, I would like to know how to notify a user when someone accept a request from them (which mean the second persons accepted the request and update to the mysql database).

Can anyone advice on how to design the structure of program in the android client side so that it will check the status of the request from a Table in database and notify the user when the status of request changed.

Thanks for any helps.

Comment: android cannot directly interact with mysql. there's no mysql drivers for android, and you would definitely NOT want to make your mysql accessible to the general public anyways. Create a webservice that mediates between android and PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you have your own website you can create a cronjob which check the column status in  (e.g. database) for each confirmed requests the send  push notification then change the column to sent for example.
also , you can create a service in your application to check the status of request and notify the user about it.
Note : do not make the period of checking database very close , it will drain your battery.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should check your database e.g.  like every second, but, as is stated, using a webpage. It may event be with no visual side.

`index.php`

```
class Synchroniser {
public void CheckStatus() {
//here you check what is up in database
return $status;
}
```

`your program` in a thread you do:

```
while(1) {
status = CallWebPage();
}
```